# Are "&&" and "," the same in Swift?

Tags: swift

As the title says, I just came across a case where if `&&` (AND) and `,` give the same result in Swift. I tested the code below:

```
let a = 5
let b = 6

if a<6, b>0 {
    print("should be true")
}

if a<6, b<0 {
    print("should be false")
}

if a>6, b>0 {
    print("should be false")
}

if a>6, b<0 {
    print("should be false")
}
```

It only logs:

> should be true

So, the behavior of `,` is just like `&&`, am I correct?

Comment: It appears to be true for `if` statements, but you can't write code like `return (a > 4, b < 4)` so the two are not identical

Comment: Practically it behaves like a *condition-list* after `guard`, `if let` and `guard let`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

They can be used in similar situations but that does not mean they are exactly the same.

Consider:

```
if (a && b) || c
```

you cannot write

```
if (a, b) || c
```

even `a && b || c` is different from `a, b || c`.

`if a, b` is something like

```
if a {
   if b {
      ...
   }
}
```

Both expressions have to be evaluated to `true` but they are still two separate expressions. We shouldn't imagine `&&` there.

Why do we need the `,` operator?

The operator is needed to combine optional binding with boolean conditions, e.g.

```
if let a = a, a.isValid() {
```

becuase `&&` wouldn't help us in such situations.

Comment: To add on, I would use `&&` for clarity if that is really what you want. If you use `,` to substitute `&&`, people might be confused, do a double-take, or mistake it as a typo/bug, even if the code is correct/understandable.

Comment: Also for clarity, you could add a new line for each test when using ,  . This enable people Redding your code to understand that these are different tests. The most frequent usage I saw for using , is testing optionals like in {if let a=someoptional, a.oneproperty == somevalue {}}

Answer (score 6):

They're different in that a comma will take the lowest precedence possible. i.e everything else will be executed before the commas are checked.

```
// (true || false) && false
if true || false, false {
    print("I will never be executed")
}

// true || (false && false)
if true || false && false {
    print("I am always executed")
}
```

Comment: This is good information, but I think it's best to illustrate as the comma being the same as `&&` with parenthetical regrouping. i.e. `true || false, false` is `(true || false) && false`.